# Multiple Replacements with JS / RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Following problem occurrs: replacement works as expected but: all findings are replaced with the first find. (Example below code).

target = input field containing the to-be-highlighted string;
newCityString = the html code, where the replacement should be done

```
/**
*   Highlighting for Search results (just demo)
*   TODO: This needs some work to replace the case-correct texts
*/
search = new RegExp( $(target).val() , 'gi' );
matches = search.exec(newCityString);
for( match in matches ) {
    _this = new RegExp( matches[ match ], 'gi');
    newCityString = newCityString.replace( 
        _this,
        ('<span class="hl" style="background-color:yellow">' + matches[ match ] + '</span>') 
    );
};
```

**Example:**

"Findling finds a fine fish" searching for "fin" would be "findling finds a fine fish".

This means: in some cases, the capitalization will be wrong. Where's the mistake?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use:

```
search = new RegExp( $(target).val() , 'gi' );
newCityString = newCityString.replace(search,function(substr){
    return '<span class="hl" style="background-color:yellow">' + substr + '</span>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
search = new RegExp($(target).val(), 'gi');
newCityString = newCityString.replace(search, function(match) {
  return '<span class="hl" style="background-color:yellow">' + match + '</span>';
});
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/NXmyn/)** is the working code.